# Image movement like Google Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, image, move, panning

I have an big image which I need to show in a smaller container (or smthg like this). The user should be able to move the image up, down, left & right. It should be like Google Maps.

Do you have an idea where I can start and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like [DeepZoom](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DeepZoom.aspx) would work.

---

You could also create a simple UserControl or CustomControl with panning functionality, e.g. have a canvas which handles some mouse events to manipulate a TranslateTransform on your image which should be a child of the canvas.

Event handling outline:

```
// Add this transform to the image as RenderTransform
private TranslateTransform _translateT = new TranslateTransform();
private Point _lastMousePos = new Point();

private void This_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs 
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == PanningMouseButton)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.ScrollAll;
        _lastMousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        this.CaptureMouse();
    }
}

private void This_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == PanningMouseButton)
    {
        this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
}

private void This_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
    {
        Point newMousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector shift = newMousePos - _lastMousePos;
        _translateT.X += shift.X;
        _translateT.Y += shift.Y;
        _lastMousePos = newMousePos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. DeepZoom seems to be a nice solution but a litte bit overloaded.

Comment: Added another suggestion outline which is worse in terms of performance for huge images but is more simple.

Comment: Thank you H.B.! It works for me and the performance is not that bad ;)

Comment: Nice; Unless you are still looking for better solutions you could accept this by clicking the checkmark on the left of my answer.

Comment: could you guys please be more specific as to how good the performance is? How big is the image loaded? thanks